# Two different kinds of dual of a vector

Tags: dual-spaces

So there is a dual that converts vectors to bivectors and scalars to pseudoscalars (by multiplying by the pseudoscalar).

There is also a dual that converts vectors to covectors (one-forms).

Am I correct in assuming that these are two completely different duals or are they somehow the same even though I dont see how they could be?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one is called the Hodge dual and the other is called the Algebraic dual.